# equivalent slick query to for yield

Tags: scala, slick

This was query written in slick using a for loop. Here `user` is table name and I am trying to update firstName, lastName of a user . When update completes successfully I am trying to return userId, firstName, lastName, false to user.

```
(for {
  _ <- user.filter(_.id ==== id)
            .map(_.map(u => (u.firstName,u.lastName)))
            .update((firstName,lastName))
} yield (user.id.get, firstName, lastName, false))
```

I am trying to get equivalent query without using a for comprehension. Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: There is a lot unclear about this snippet.  What is providing the `====` (quadruple-equals) method?  What is `user` such that you get a nested `map` call that works with `update`?

Comment: sorry for providing you wrong snippet . I just updated the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found equivalent query which works same as previous query without using for comprehension.

```
user.filter(_.id === id).map(_.map(u => (u.firstName, u.lastName)))
.update((firstName,lastName))
.map(_ => (user.id.get,firstName,lastName,false))
```